# System.Text.Json: How to serialize an enum dictionary key as number

Tags: c#, json, .net, enums, system.text.json

Is it possible to serialize an enum dictionary key as a number? Example:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  One = 1,
  Two = 2
}

JsonSerializer.Serialize(new Dictionary<MyEnum, int>
{
   [MyEnum.One] = 1,
   [MyEnum.Two] = 2
});

Output:
{"1":1,"2":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom converter which will support writing dictionary keys:

```cs
class JsonEnumNumberConverter : JsonConverter<MyEnum>
{
    public override MyEnum Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override void WriteAsPropertyName(Utf8JsonWriter writer, MyEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
         writer.WritePropertyName(value.ToString("D"));
}
```

And example usage (or pass in settings for `Serialize` method):

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonEnumNumberConverter))]
public enum MyEnum
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

Or use `JsonStringEnumMemberConverter` from [`Macross.Json.Extensions`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions/) which scans for `EnumMemberAttribute`:

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonStringEnumMemberConverter))]  
public enum MyEnum
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "1")]
    One,
    [EnumMember(Value = "2")]
    Two
}
```

Comment: It seems like this code would always convert this enum to a string, rather than only in the case of it being used as a dictionary key. It also has the issue of being specific to a single enum, when no one wants to write a converter class for each of their 100 enums.

Comment: @Justin it is not that hard to update the code to handle any enum. Also OP have never stated that the enum should be handled in this way only for dictionaries

Comment: @Justin Also the second mentioned option should work if the converter is added to serializer options (and not via attribute)

Comment: Just a quick upvote for Guru's last comment - this actually made it work: "the converter is added to serializer options (and not via attribute)"